# Ruby On Rails different views for same action (Based on User's role)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a ruby on rails controller that will display a different form for a logged out user than a logged in user.

What is the best way to approach this? (Is the below way ok?)

```
   class UsersController < ApplicationController
      def index
        if logged_in && is_admin
          render 'admin_index'
        end
        #use default index
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure thats fine except you might get a 'cannot render action twice' type error (if im admin and logged in it still would try to render  the default after rendering the admin action)

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController
      def index
        if logged_in && is_admin
          render 'admin_index'
        else
          render 
        end

      end
    end
```

might be better

Comment: Alternatively, I believe `render 'admin_index' and return` would work, to avoid the `else` clause.

Comment: Also, `logged_in?` and `is_admin?` are preferable, even when they are column names.

Answer (score 1):

You can always do this:

```
if condition
render :page and return
```

Just as you can do this:

```
if condition
redirect_to and return
```